# Why is my android database keep inserting into row id =0 everytime i save a new entry?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a database that holds four pieces of information, when i click save the log cat message says that it is inserted into row id =0 (this is the case everytime). It has only started doing this recently and i cannot for the life of me work it out. 
Also because of this, it is also not populating my list view anymore either. Does anyone have any idea please?

```
05-01 07:41:05.500: D/DAO(3711): Insert ROWID = 0
05-01 07:41:05.540: I/DiaryEntry(3711): onPause
05-01 07:41:05.810: I/DiaryList(3711): onResume
05-01 07:41:05.880: I/DiaryList(3711): cursor refreshed in onresume
05-01 07:41:05.930: V/PhoneStatusBar(1622): setLightsOn(true)
05-01 07:41:06.170: I/Choreographer(3711): Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be   doing too much work on its main thread.
05-01 07:41:06.720: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-01 07:41:10.150: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 844 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-01 07:41:13.250: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 803 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-01 07:41:15.560: W/ActivityManager(1266): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
05-01 07:41:16.680: I/DiaryEntry(3711): onStop
05-01 07:41:16.680: I/DiaryEntry(3711): onDestroy
05-01 07:41:16.790: I/Choreographer(3711): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-01 07:41:19.820: I/ActivityManager(1266): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher} from pid 1266
05-01 07:41:19.860: D/gralloc(914): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
05-01 07:41:19.860: E/libEGL(914): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-01 07:41:19.860: E/libEGL(914): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-01 07:41:19.860: E/libEGL(914): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-01 07:41:19.860: E/libEGL(914): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-01 07:41:19.860: E/SurfaceFlinger(914): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error -1963549556
05-01 07:41:19.860: E/SurfaceFlinger(914): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
05-01 07:41:19.860: E/libEGL(914): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-01 07:41:19.860: E/libEGL(914): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
```

Comment: Show your code. Otherwise, how can we help you?

Comment: i have shown my log cat messages if that helps, or would the save code be better?

Comment: It seems you are doing all on the main thread... the code is mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check your database for insertion actually happens. There is a one more reason that you are not printing the exception stack trace in your code. And because of that , you are not getting proper information for error